# Multithreaded Hibernate application waiting to lock ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, c3p0

I have a multithreaded application (100 threads) that is trying to write to a DB. 
I see writes going through, but at a very slow rate.

When I took a thread dump, I noticed that 80 of the 100 threads  are waiting at

```
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.amazon.odin.hibernate.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:143)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007bdc5cc70> (a com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection pool only has `20` connections, so the threads are competing for that resource. Note that it won't help if you raise the amount of connections to `100` if your database can't handle it. Then you're just moving the competing from the connection pool to the DB resources.

However if your DB server does have enough juice, you could consider increasing the max connections in your pool and see how that affects the throughput.